# Add a link inside jQuery tooltip function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have been looking for a while, and maybe I'm not using the right terminology, but I'm trying to find out how to put a link inside of the jQuery tooltip, so when it pops up, I can display a menu in it. Can I just write the link out in the title like `title="<a href=""></a>">`

**Here is what I currently have for my tooltip**

```
      $(function() {
        $( document ).tooltip({
          position: {
            my: "center bottom-20",
            at: "center top",
            using: function( position, feedback ) {
              $( this ).css( position );
              $( "<div>" )
                .addClass( "arrow" )
                .addClass( feedback.vertical )
                .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
                .appendTo( this );
            }
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Using jQuery UI or any other plug-in?

Comment: jQuery tooltip is only in the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically insert content to the tooltip you can subscribe to the "open" event of the tooltip.

http://jsfiddle.net/PagNg/

Example:-

```
$( "a" ).tooltip({
  open: function( event, ui ) {
      $(ui.tooltip).append('<a href="http:\\www.google.com">google</a>');
  }
});
```

Comment: But *tooltip* disappeared when moving over it! how to keep it appeared to be able to click link ?

Answer (score 2):

jQueryUI tooltips don't stick around if the user hovers off the element.

Adding a link to a jQueryUI tooltip is a bad idea in the first place since the user will not be able to click it (unless you are really fast)

Answer (score 1):

The `title` attribute will most likely not meet your needs if you want more sophisticated tooltips. Here are some suggestions:

#### Build it yourself

Have a hidden div somewhere in your dom and use it to replace the standard tooltip. Use jQuery to display it and position it wherever it is needed. Use in conjunction with jQueryUI's content option if you wish.

```
<div id="tooltip">
  <div class="tooltipText"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Use a different tooltip  plugin

Here are 25 different tooltips, some of which allow you to put anything you like inside the tooltip.
http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/25-useful-resources-for-creating-tooltips-with-javascript-or-css/

Answer (score 1):

You can comment the following line regarding pointer events -

```
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;   
  text-align: center;   
  width: 60px;  
  height: 28px;     
  padding: 2px; 
  font: 12px sans-serif;    
  background: lightsteelblue;   
  border: 0px;                  
  border-radius: 8px;

 /*  pointer-events: none;  This line needs to be removed */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The native design of the tooltip rely on different assumptions, so the behaviour you need (a sticky tooltip that allows the user to click its content) is not officially supported.

Anyway looking at this link you can see it's possibile to achieve what you need using jQuery Tools:

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.html

Here is a standalone demo

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.htm

Comment: jQueryTools never really had it figured out. You had to manually write a copious amount of HTML markup by hand. It was a tedious implementation. Regardless, jQueryTools is now dead so I think this answer should be removed.